# Removing background around text-heavy image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Recently lost my father and going among papers I discovered a sheet depicting our family coat of arms, along with text explaining all the details and a brief history of the family name.

It is delicate, the paper appears to be something similar to tracing paper, and the paper has yellowed just slightly and the old school typewriter generated text is not black but grey.

I scanned it and opened it in Photoshop CS4 and adjusted the brightness and contrast to enhance the text and drawing of the crest. Sadly that made the background a dark grey with a bunch of imperfections.

Is it possible to take out that background without losing the detail etc in the scanned text/crest? I do not know much about how to use curves in PS but I toyed with it and if I turned on "show clipping" it looked pretty good, meaning the background went to white.

I know there won't be a perfect answer but is there a reasonable compromise? I will rewrite the text and trace the crest by hand at some point, but for now I'd like to preserve as much info/detail from this old parchment-esque document as possible in case it finally disintegrates. There is probably extra info within all the details and decorative scrolling border on the page.Thanks so much for any help

Comment: I'm afraid it may be necessary to see at least a small cropped portion of the image to provide definitive answers.

Comment: There are some cases where you can extract information from a file.

There are cases where you can not. If that is the case consider it to an expert to **redraw and recreate** what it can not be done automatically.

Comment: Any chance you could share your scanned image? It's hard to give advice when we can't see it.